# highgui.imread function Not working

Tags: android, opencv

I'm using highgui.imread function for reading an image in Android(Eclipse). But when I'm printing the size of the image it's printing (0,0).

Mat image = Highgui.imread(fname);

Can someone please tell me why is it so??

Comment: Probably because the image you are trying to read doesn't exist. Make sure the actual path to the image is correct.

Comment: The path is correct. I already checked that by printing.

Comment: Image could also be corrupted. Did you check its integrity? Open it in other software or another viewer? Btw please give ALL of the details to your problem and what you have tried. It's not our job to play 20 questions. You give us all the details to minimize the work for us.

Comment: I'm using face detection algorithm code in android with opencv libraries. For this I'm firstly browsing the image and then trying to detect the particular object in that with the help of : Mat image = Highgui.imread(recordedFilePath); command with the help of browsed image address. After this when I'm printing the size of the image, I'm getting it as 0,0.

Comment: I have tried it on different images also but still not working.